# Web User Control not visible in Default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

What gives? My previously created user control is visible, but the newly created one is not - intellisence doesn't show it,

I was under the impression that you don't need to put any using statements or references in the project if the web user control is in the same project.

UPDATED:
both declarations look something like this:

```
public partial class CtrlClassName : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

Comment: I think this would be easier to answer if you included the code and ascx/aspx markup.

Comment: Can you give more details? Do you mean it is not visible in the designer or in the browser? Did you try Rebuild All? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the proper @register in Default.aspx.  See  [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx) for reference.

Example:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="pfx" TagName="CtrlClassName" Src="Controls/CtrlClassName.ascx" %>
```

Comment: aha, that was the culprit. I forgot the Register completely.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Good luck on your project.